# How to pass request headers using async node library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, asynchronous, runkit

I’m using the [async-get-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-get-json) library to call a REST API. 
I’m unclear as to the parameter structure of the request structure and unfortunately there is no readme or docs available for the lib.

I’d like help passing an array of request headers to the getJson(...) function?

There is a runkit example at the top of [this](https://runkit.com/docs/await) page that you can fiddle with!

Comment: It looks like most of the modules by [@tolmasky](https://twitter.com/tolmasky) are tests for runkit (his twitter bio says "CEO and Founder of [@runkitdev](https://twitter.com/runkitdev)"). I'd ping him to see if this is a legit module and then ask for the source code repo. On a side note: I am not sure why you would ever use an NPM module without having access to the source code. And yes, while it is easy to link source code that is in fact not the source code for the NPM module, that is generally not the case and you can always load from the source directly anyway.

Comment: @JasonCust you need to just install module, and you will see source code inside `node_modules` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I advice you use [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) instead?

Or [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) if you prefer callback style